# 360 degree video stalling in youtube application

Tags: youtube, cobalt, 360-degrees

Herewith we are facing the data stalling in 360 video in youtube application and also observed in more content for example videoID of '**HemwKBjQ0Uc**'(**【VR】Elemental Demo - 60fps 4k 8k Stereo 360 with Ambisonic audio**). In problematic case, buffer is removing from the RangeList using next range(`DeleteAndRemoveRange(&next_range_itr)`) and also problem observed within 30-60 secs for above mentioned content. And also we are using Cobalt *13.11* version, `MergeWithAdjacentRangeIfNecessary()` API has been problematic from our analysis. And also for our internal validation, we have increased the non video budget and 1080p resolution upto 50 MB, Data stallation has not been observed in 360 video and content was playing contionously for that content. For your information, We have checked with ***latest cobalt*** application and observed the same behaviour.

Please advise us to conclude this issue.

Comment: Hi I'm not sure if I understand the issue, what do you mean exactly by "data stalling"?

You mention Cobalt version 13, however we do not support that version, there may be bugs in it.  Please try a version of Cobalt on a release branch, such as 19.lts.1+: https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/19.lts.1+ , as the issue may be addressed there.

Comment: Data Stalling- Video frame didn’t recieve to ffmpeg_video_decoder even after giving kNeedMoreInput but audio data receiving as usual continuously. Can you please try to play a above mentioned video. And also we already have ensured in latest cobalt 19+ also having this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Data Stalling- Video frame didn’t recieve to ffmpeg_video_decoder even after giving kneedbuffer but audio data receiving as usual continuously. Can you please try to play a above mentioned video. And also we already have ensured in latest cobalt 19+ also having this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to increase the video buffer budget set by variables like COBALT_MEDIA_BUFFER_VIDEO_BUDGET_4K and COBALT_MEDIA_BUFFER_MAX_CAPACITY_4K?

Answer (score 0):

Yes xiaoming. We have already tried this and working fine but we need to know the reason of appndbuffer not happening while after this call happens (DeleteAndRemoveRange(&next_range_itr))